# Filter table with ajax

Tags: ajax

My code is not working

//this is feedback_data.php  code

```
          <select  id="fetchval" name="fetchval">
             <option disabled selected>Please select year</option>
             <option value="2023">2023</option>
             <option value="2024">2024</option>

          </select>

                                <div class="feedback_container">  
                                    <table id="feed_table" class="display table table-striped" style="width:100%">

                                        <thead>

                                            <tr style="text-align:center;">

                                                <th>ID</th>

                                                <th>Full Name</th>

                                                <th>Email</th>

                                                <th>Age</th>
                                                
                                                <th>Sex</th>
                                                
                                                <th>Client Type</th>
                                                
                                                <th>Service Availed</th>
                                                
                                                <th>Other Service</th>
                                                
                                                <th>Region</th>
                                                
                                                <th>CC1</th>
                                                
                                                <th>CC2</th>
                                                
                                                <th>CC3</th>
                                                
                                                <th>SQD0 Overall</th>
                                                
                                                <th>SQD1 Responsiveness</th>
                                                
                                                <th>SQD2 Reliability</th>
                                                
                                                <th>SQD3 Access and Facilities</th>
                                                
                                                <th>SQD4 Communication</th>
                                                
                                                <th>SQD5 Costs</th>
                                                
                                                <th>SQD6 Integrity</th>
                                                
                                                <th>SQD7 Assurance</th>
                                                
                                                <th>SQD8 Outcome</th>
                                                
                                                 <th>Quarter</th>

                                                <th>Timestamp</th>
                                                
                                              

                                            </tr>

                                        </thead>

                                        <tbody>



                                             <?php               

                                include "includes/connection.php";
                                include "php/summary.php";
                                include 'php/year.php';
                                $sql2="SELECT * FROM feedback";

                                $sel2=$conn->query($sql2);

                                while($row2=$sel2->fetch_assoc()){

                                  ?>

                                            <tr>

                                                <td><?= $row2['id'] ?></td>

                                                <td><?= $row2['name'] ?></td>

                                                <td><?= $row2['email'] ?></td>

                                              

                                                <td><?= $row2['age'] ?></td>

                                                <td><?= $row2['sex'] ?></td>
                                                
                                                <td><?= $row2['client_type'] ?></td>
                                                
                                         
                                                
                                                <td><?= $row2['service'] ?></td>
                                                <td><?= $row2['other_service'] ?></td>
                                                
                                                <td><?= $row2['region'] ?></td>
                                                
                                                <td><?= $row2['cc1'] ?></td>
                                                <td><?= $row2['cc2'] ?></td>
                                                <td><?= $row2['cc3'] ?></td>
                                                
                                               
                                                <td><?= $row2['sqd0_overall'] ?></td>   
                                                <td><?= $row2['responsiveness'] ?></td> 
                                                <td><?= $row2['reliability'] ?></td>    
                                                <td><?= $row2['access_and_facilities'] ?></td>  
                                                <td><?= $row2['communication'] ?></td>  
                                                <td><?= $row2['costs'] ?></td>  
                                                <td><?= $row2['integrity'] ?></td>  
                                                <td><?= $row2['assurance'] ?></td>  
                                                <td><?= $row2['outcome'] ?></td>
                                                
                                                <td><?= $row2['quarter'] ?></td>
                                                
                                                <td><?= $row2['date_time'] ?></td>

                                            </tr>

                                       <?php } ?>

                                        </tbody>

                                    </table>
                                </div>
```

$(document).ready(function() {       
                                            
                    $("#fetchval").on('change', function(){
                        
                        var value = $(this).val();
                        // alert(value);
                
                        $.ajax({
                           url:"php/fetch_feed.php", 
                           type:"POST",
                           data:'request=' + value;
                           beforeSend:function(){
                               $(".feedback_container").html("Loading...");
                           },
                           success:function(data){
                               $(".feedback_container").html(data);
                           }
                        });                               
                        });
                         });

//this is my code for fetch_feed.php

```
          <?php
                include './includes/connection.php';

                if(isset($_POST['request'])){
                    
                    $request = $_POST['request'];
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM feedback WHERE year = '$request'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);



                ?>

                <table id="feed_table" class="display table table-striped" style="width:100%">
                    
                    <?php
                    
                    if($count){
                        
                        ?>

                        <thead>

                            <tr style="text-align:center;">

                                <th>ID</th>

                                <th>Full Name</th>

                                <th>Email</th>

                            

                                <th>Age</th>
                                
                                <th>Sex</th>
                                
                                <th>Client Type</th>
                                
                             
                                
                                <th>Service Availed</th>
                                <th>Other Service</th>
                                
                                <th>Region</th>
                                
                                <th>CC1</th>
                                
                                <th>CC2</th>
                                
                                <th>CC3</th>
                                
                                <th>SQD0 Overall</th>
                                
                                <th>SQD1 Responsiveness</th>
                                
                                <th>SQD2 Reliability</th>
                                
                                <th>SQD3 Access and Facilities</th>
                                
                                <th>SQD4 Communication</th>
                                
                                <th>SQD5 Costs</th>
                                
                                <th>SQD6 Integrity</th>
                                
                                <th>SQD7 Assurance</th>
                                
                                <th>SQD8 Outcome</th>
                                
                                 <th>Quarter</th>

                                <th>Timestamp</th>
                                
                              

                            </tr>

                     
                        
                        
                        <?php
                    }else{
                        echo "Sorry No Record";
                    }
                        
                        ?>
                        
                           </thead>
                           
                              <tbody>
                            <?php      
                                  while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                  ?>
                        
                        
                         <tr>

                                <td><?php echo $row2['id'] ?></td>

                                <td><?php echo $row2['name'] ?></td>

                                <td><?php echo $row2['email'] ?></td>

                              

                                <td><?php echo $row2['age'] ?></td>

                                <td><?php echo $row2['sex'] ?></td>
                                
                                <td><?php echo $row2['client_type'] ?></td>
                                
                         
                                
                                <td><?php echo $row2['service'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['other_service'] ?></td>
                                
                                <td><?php echo $row2['region'] ?></td>
                                
                                <td><?php echo $row2['cc1'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['cc2'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['cc3'] ?></td>
                                
                               
                                <td><?php echo $row2['sqd0_overall'] ?></td>  
                                <td><?php echo $row2['responsiveness'] ?></td>  
                                <td><?php echo $row2['reliability'] ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $row2['access_and_facilities'] ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $row2['communication'] ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $row2['costs'] ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $row2['integrity'] ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $row2['assurance'] ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $row2['outcome'] ?></td>
                                
                                <td><?php echo $row2['quarter'] ?></td>
                                
                                <td><?php echo $row2['date_time'] ?></td>

                          

                            </tr>
                        
                        <?php
                        
                                  }
                                  
                                  ?>
                        
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                        
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
```

The code is not working, it should filter the table based on selected value on select tag

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pCda.png)